# pass more data than pixel space from shader to C++ program

Tags: c++, opengl

I now want to create a light path in OpenGL shader and pass the positions of light nodes along the path back to my main program in order to create a bvh tree.

I've found a solving method using `glGetTexImage` like:

```cpp
void Renderer::GetOutputBufferForLightPath(unsigned char **data, int &w, int &h)
{
    w = renderSize.x;
    h = renderSize.y;

    *data = new unsigned char[w * h * 3];

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, lightPathNodesTexture);

    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, *data);
}
```

And the final problem is to generate the lightPathNodesTexture in my shader, however, I don't know how to. If I use a pathtracer to generate 10 light points along the path, I cannot store all the positions (10 xyz with 30 floats) in a `GL_RGB` space to pass them out.